# Doubt about mathematical induction and inequalities

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, induction

I have to use the induction principle to prove/disprove the following inequality:

$n^2-4n-2<0$  when $n>1$

It is easy to see that this inequality isn't correct when $n>4$ However, I'm not sure if the way I propose the solution is correct.

If we complete the induction step we get this expression:

$(n^2-4n-2)+(2n-3)<0$

The value included inside the first parenthesis is the same as the induction hypothesis, so we can assume that it's a negative value. On the other hand, since $n$ takes values greater than $1$, the value inside the second parenthesis will be always positive. Therefore, we can assert that this inequality is wrong.

Is this reasoning enough to prove it or do I need something else?

Comment: Seems like a bizarre problem.  As you say, the claim is obviously false.  I don't see your argument as an "inductive proof" of that but then I don't see what induction has to do with it.  A single counter example, say $n=5$, settles the problem completely.

Comment: Not clear what your question is, but if you want to _disprove_ the claim "$n^2 - 4n - 2 < 0$ when $n > 1$", $n=5$ is already a counterexample.

Comment: *Therefore, we can assert that this inequality is wrong.*: You can only say  that you cannot prove it by induction. You already proved it wrong by a counterexample.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to prove $n^2-4n-2 \geq 0$ when $n > 4$. Try to prove that instead

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=5$ then $n^2-4n-2 = 25 - 22 = 3 > 0$. This is a counter-example of the fact stated that the inequality holds for $n> 1$. So this is a false claim.

> **Different Claim:** $n^2-4n-2>0$ for all $n\geq5$.

For $n=5$ we showed that it is true in the arguments above. This is the base of the induction. Now lets suppose that it is a true statement and do the step of the induction. Then

$$(n+1)^2-4(n+1)-2 = n^2+2n+1-4n-4-2 = \underbrace{(n^2-4n-2)}_{>0 \text{ hypothesis  }} + (2n-3)$$

Try to proceed from here. This will show that there is no $n$ greater or equal than $5$ such that the statement of the question is true.